# Как добавить новый framework в Xcode, чтобы не было ошибок?

Tags: ios, xcode, framework, apple

Как правильно импортировать *framework*, чтобы он работал и не было ошибок при анализе?

У меня приложения созданы на движке, использую специальный плагин, который должен добавить рекламу Admob в приложение, но там вручную нужно добавить *framework Iron Source* (я так понимаю SDK) и *Mobile SDK* от Гугл. Я скачала эти фреймворки, по-разному пробую их добавить в проект, но при анализе выдаётся ошибка, хотя я указывала на ссылки в Target. Как это правильно сделать? Расскажите по подробнее.

Comment: ошибку можно посмотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Для любых стороних фреймворков старайтесь использовать менеджер зависимостей, например - [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) - установка есть на странице. 
 Зайдите в директорию вашего проекта через консоль, введите команду - `pod init`, будет создан Podfile, в него добавтье необходимый фреймворк:

```
target 'YourProject' do
   use_frameworks!
   pod 'Firebase/AdMob'

end
```

Затем команду `pod install` или же `pod update`. Единственное - запускать проект нужно через файл ***.xcworkspace**.